# Validation of ASP.NET Core options during startup

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core

Core2 has a hook for validating options read from `appsettings.json`:

```
services.PostConfigure<MyConfig>(options => {
  // do some validation
  // maybe throw exception if appsettings.json has invalid data
});
```

This validation code triggers on first use of `MyConfig`, and every time after that. So I get multiple runtime errors.

*However it is more sensible to run validation during startup* - if config validation fails I want the app to fail immediately. The [docs imply that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.1#ipostconfigureoptions) is how it works, but that is not what happens.

So am I doing it right? If so and this is by design, then how can I change what I'm doing so it works the way I want?

(Also, what is the difference between `PostConfigure` and `PostConfigureAll`? There is no difference in this case, so when should I use either one?)

Comment: Here is an article that argues against injecting IOptions<T> and suggest a work around. https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetintegration.html#working-with-ioptions-t

Comment: @Nkosi that's an interesting take on the matter, will reconsider, thanks.

Comment: @Nkosi: I highly disagree with the linked documentation, since first the `IOptions<T>` can be configured in the same way the when using `services.Configure<T>(instanceOfT)`,second `IOptionsSnapshot<T>` also offers reloading of the settings while the application runs. Third, the singleton settings can be pretty problematic, when someone changes the value in it, while a request is already in progress. That way the request may have started with one value for an option and may end with a different one. With `IOptions<T>` this can't happen (only within the request) because it has a scoped life-time

Comment: If one really wants to validate the configuration, one could create a scoped provider in `Configure` method, resolve and check/validate the configuration there (i.e. by resolving the option and access/validating its parameters). When here an error happens the app won't start

Comment: @Tseng Agreed. I was just presenting different arguments to weigh the pros and cons available. The configure suggestion looks very good and is similar to the provided answer. One of my concern was coupling to the framework concern but that can abstracted another layer down as well.

Comment: @Tseng yes that is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no real way to run a configuration validation during startup. As you already noticed, post configure actions run, just like normal configure actions, lazily when the options object is being requested. This completely by design, and allows for many important features, for example reloading configuration during run-time or also options cache invalidation.

What the post configuration action is usually being used for is not a validation in terms of *“if there’s something wrong, then throw an exception”*, but rather *“if there’s something wrong, fall back to sane defaults and make it work”*.

For example, there’s a post configuration step in the authentication stack, that makes sure that there’s always a `SignInScheme` set for remote authentication handlers:

```
options.SignInScheme = options.SignInScheme ?? _authOptions.DefaultSignInScheme ?? _authOptions.DefaultScheme;
```

As you can see, this will not fail but rather just provides multiple fallbacks.

In this sense, it’s also important to remember that options and configuration are actually two separate things. It’s just that the configuration is a commonly used source for configuring options. So one might argue that it is not actually the job of the options to validate that the configuration is correct.

As such it might make more sense to actually check the configuration in the Startup, before configuring the options. Something like this:

```
var myOptionsConfiguration = Configuration.GetSection("MyOptions");

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myOptionsConfiguration["Url"]))
    throw new Exception("MyOptions:Url is a required configuration");

services.Configure<MyOptions>(myOptionsConfiguration);
```

Of course this easily becomes very excessive, and will likely force you to bind/parse many properties manually. It will also ignore the configuration chaining that the options pattern supports (i.e. configuring a single options object with multiple sources/actions).

So what you could do here is keep your post configuration action for validation, and simply trigger the validation during startup by actually requesting the options object. For example, you could simply add `IOptions<MyOptions>` as a dependency to the `Startup.Configure` method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IOptions<MyOptions> myOptions)
{
    // all configuration and post configuration actions automatically run

    // …
}
```

If you have multiple of these options, you could even move this into a separate type:

```
public class OptionsValidator
{
    public OptionsValidator(IOptions<MyOptions> myOptions, IOptions<OtherOptions> otherOptions)
    { }
}
```

At that time, you could also move the logic from the post configuration action into that `OptionsValidator`. So you could trigger the validation explicitly as part of the application startup:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, OptionsValidator optionsValidator)
{
    optionsValidator.Validate();

    // …
}
```

As you can see, there’s no single answer for this. You should think about your requirements and see what makes the most sense for your case. And of course, this whole validation only makes sense for certain configurations. In particular, you will have difficulties when working configurations that will change during run-time (you *could* make this work with a custom options monitor, but it’s probably not worth the hassle). But as most own applications usually just use cached `IOptions<T>`, you likely don’t need that.

---

As for `PostConfigure` and `PostConfigureAll`, they both register an `IPostConfigure<TOptions>`. The difference is simply that the former will only match a single *named* option (by default the unnamed option—if you don’t care about option names), while `PostConfigureAll` will run for all names.

Named options are for example used for the authentication stack, where each authentication method is identified by its scheme name. So you could for example add multiple OAuth handlers and use `PostConfigure("oauth-a", …)` to configure one and `PostConfigure("oauth-b", …)` to configure the other, or use `PostConfigureAll(…)` to configure them both.

Comment: You start by saying that it's not possible, then go on to give me a very detailed answer with a great solution! :-) Your `OptionsValidator` idea is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: You do raise an interesting point though - what if the config changes at runtime? Then the validation should run again. Is there a hook you know of that is triggered when config sources change? You say a custom options monitor but that is probably overkill, no? I checked the docs site for something similar to `PostConfigure` that is raised when config changes, but didn't find anything - do you know of something like that?

Comment: Usually, you would likely just use `IOptions<T>` everywhere. You only get support for reloading configurations when you use `IOptionsSnapshot<T>` or the lower-level `IOptionsMonitor<T>` though. If you do choose to implement your validation using a post-configure action, of course that will also run when a changed configuration is being used to reconfigure the options. But that will necessarily run at run-time then, and not at startup. – In practice though, I don’t see that many use cases for changing configuration though, so maybe you don’t even need to think about that.

Comment: Oh, and I said that it is not possible because the Options stuff does not support this (out of the box). But that of course does not mean that we will have to live with that restriction, hence me giving some ideas for how to solve it anway :)

Comment: This answer is no longer correct.

Answer (score 30):

### Startup validation (.NET 6 and above)

This has been discussed in this [dotnet/runtime issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36391).

In **.NET 6**, a `ValidateOnStart` extension method has been added to [`Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting).

You can use it this way:

```cs
services.AddOptions<MyOptions>()
    .ValidateDataAnnotations()
    .ValidateOnStart();                 // Support eager validation
```

Note that prior to **.NET 8**, `ValidateDataAnnotations` did not validate nested properties (see solution below).

### Recursive DataAnnotation validation (.NET 8 and above)

This has been discussed in this [dotnet/runtime issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36093).

In **.NET 8**, `[ValidateObjectMembers]` and `[ValidateEnumeratedItems]` attributes have been added to [`Microsoft.Extensions.Options`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Options).

You can use `[ValidateObjectMembers]` on an **object property** or `[ValidateEnumeratedItems]` on an **enumerable property**, and their nested objects will be validated recursively.

There is a [trick for dictionaries](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/97873).

```cs
public class ApplicationOptions
{
    [ValidateObjectMembers]
    public SecurityOptions Security { get; set; }

    [ValidateEnumeratedItems]
    public IEnumerable<ProviderOptions> Providers { get; set; }

    // Specific case of the dictionary
    public Dictionary<string, MyOptions> DictionaryOfMyOptions { get; set; }
    [ValidateEnumeratedItems]
    public IEnumerable<MyOptions> MyOptionsValues => DictionaryOfMyOptions.Values;

    ...
}

public class SecurityOptions
{
    [Required]
    public PasswordOptions Password { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class PasswordOptions
{
    [Range(8, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be greater than {1}.")]
    public int MinLength { get; set; } = 8;

    ...
}
```

### Alternative for previous .NET version (or if you don't want to use specific attributes)

This [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReHackt.Extensions.Options.Validation) provides a `ConfigureAndValidate<TOptions>` extension method which validates options at startup.

It is based on Microsoft.Extensions.Options.DataAnnotations. But unlike Microsoft's package, it validates nested properties by default.

It is compatible with .NET Standard 2.0, .NET Core 3.1, .NET 5 and above.

[Documentation & source code (GitHub)](https://github.com/LionelVallet/ReHackt.Extensions.Options.Validation)

### TL;DR

1. Create your options class(es)
2. Decorate your options with data annotations
3. Call `ConfigureAndValidate<T>(Action<T> configureOptions)` on your `IServiceCollection`

`ConfigureAndValidate` will configure your options (calling the base `Configure` method), but will also check that the built configuration respects the data annotations, otherwise an OptionsValidationException (with details) is thrown as soon as the application is started. No misconfiguration surprise at runtime!

### Use

#### ServiceCollection extension

```cs
services.ConfigureAndValidate<TOptions>(configureOptions)
```

Is syntactic sugar for

```cs
services
    .AddOptions<TOptions>()
        .Configure(configureOptions) // Microsoft
        .ValidateDataAnnotationsRecursively() // based on Microsoft's ValidateDataAnnotations, but supports nested properties
        .ValidateOnStart() // or ValidateEagerly() in previous versions
        .Services
```

#### OptionsBuilder extensions

##### ValidateDataAnnotationsRecursively

This method register this options instance for validation of its DataAnnotations at the first dependency injection. Nested objects are supported.

##### ValidateOnStart (or ValidateEagerly in previous versions)

This method validates this options instance at application startup rather than at the first dependency injection.

### Custom validation

You can combine with your own option validations:

```cs
services
    .AddOptions<TOptions>()
        .Configure(configureOptions)
        //...
        .Validate(options => { /* custom */ }, message)
        .Validate<TDependency1, TDependency2>((options, dependency1, dependency2) =>
            { 
                // custom validation
            },
            "Custom error message")
        //...
        .ValidateDataAnnotationsRecursively()
        .ValidateOnStart()
```

[Microsoft options validation documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options#options-validation)

Answer (score 10):

On an ASP.NET Core 2.2 project I got this working doing ***eager*** validation by following these steps...

Given an Options class like this one:

```
public class CredCycleOptions
{
    [Range(1753, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid integer Number.")]
    public int VerifiedMinYear { get; set; }
    [Range(1753, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid integer Number.")]
    public int SignedMinYear { get; set; }
    [Range(1753, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid integer Number.")]
    public int SentMinYear { get; set; }
    [Range(1753, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid integer Number.")]
    public int ConfirmedMinYear { get; set; }
}
```

In `Startup.cs` add these lines to `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddOptions();

// This will validate Eagerly...
services.ConfigureAndValidate<CredCycleOptions>("CredCycle", Configuration);
```

`ConfigureAndValidate` is an extension method from [here](https://keestalkstech.com/2019/09/validate-strongly-typed-options-when-using-config-sections/).

```
public static class OptionsExtensions
{
    private static void ValidateByDataAnnotation(object instance, string sectionName)
    {
        var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
        var context = new ValidationContext(instance);
        var valid = Validator.TryValidateObject(instance, context, validationResults);

        if (valid)
            return;

        var msg = string.Join("\n", validationResults.Select(r => r.ErrorMessage));

        throw new Exception($"Invalid configuration for section '{sectionName}':\n{msg}");
    }

    public static OptionsBuilder<TOptions> ValidateByDataAnnotation<TOptions>(
        this OptionsBuilder<TOptions> builder,
        string sectionName)
        where TOptions : class
    {
        return builder.PostConfigure(x => ValidateByDataAnnotation(x, sectionName));
    }

    public static IServiceCollection ConfigureAndValidate<TOptions>(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        string sectionName,
        IConfiguration configuration)
        where TOptions : class
    {
        var section = configuration.GetSection(sectionName);

        services
            .AddOptions<TOptions>()
            .Bind(section)
            .ValidateByDataAnnotation(sectionName)
            .ValidateEagerly();

        return services;
    }

    public static OptionsBuilder<TOptions> ValidateEagerly<TOptions>(this OptionsBuilder<TOptions> optionsBuilder) where TOptions : class
    {
        optionsBuilder.Services.AddTransient<IStartupFilter, StartupOptionsValidation<TOptions>>();

        return optionsBuilder;
    }
}
```

I plumbed `ValidateEargerly` extension method right inside `ConfigureAndValidate`. It makes use of this other class from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/459#issuecomment-536547483):

```
public class StartupOptionsValidation<T> : IStartupFilter
{
    public Action<IApplicationBuilder> Configure(Action<IApplicationBuilder> next)
    {
        return builder =>
        {
            var options = builder.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(IOptions<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T)));

            if (options != null)
            {
                // Retrieve the value to trigger validation
                var optionsValue = ((IOptions<object>)options).Value;
            }

            next(builder);
        };
    }
}
```

This allows us to add data annotations to the `CredCycleOptions` and get nice error feedback right at the moment the app starts making it an ideal solution.

[image]

If an option is missing or have a wrong value, we don't want users to catch these errors at runtime. That would be a bad experience.

Answer (score 3):

There are easy way to validating with using `IStartupFilter` and `IValidateOptions`.

You can just put below code your ASP.NET Core project.

```cs
public static class OptionsBuilderExtensions
{
    public static OptionsBuilder<TOptions> ValidateOnStartupTime<TOptions>(this OptionsBuilder<TOptions> builder)
        where TOptions : class
    {
        builder.Services.AddTransient<IStartupFilter, OptionsValidateFilter<TOptions>>();
        return builder;
    }
    
    public class OptionsValidateFilter<TOptions> : IStartupFilter where TOptions : class
    {
        private readonly IOptions<TOptions> _options;

        public OptionsValidateFilter(IOptions<TOptions> options)
        {
            _options = options;
        }

        public Action<IApplicationBuilder> Configure(Action<IApplicationBuilder> next)
        {
            _ = _options.Value; // Trigger for validating options.
            return next;
        }
    }
}
```

And just chain the `ValidateOnStartup` method on `OptionsBuilder<TOptions>`.

```cs
services.AddOptions<SampleOption>()
    .Bind(Configuration)
    .ValidateDataAnnotations()
    .ValidateOnStartupTime();
```

If you want to create custom validator for options class, checkout [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0#ivalidateoptions-for-complex-validation).

Answer (score 3):

This has been implemented in .NET 6.  Now you can just write the following:

```cs
services.AddOptions<SampleOption>()
   .Bind(Configuration)
   .ValidateDataAnnotations()
   .ValidateOnStart(); // works in .NET 6
```

No need for external NuGet Packages or extra code.

See [`OptionsBuilderExtensions.ValidateOnStart<TOptions>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.optionsbuilderextensions.validateonstart?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

Comment: It still doesn't work for me, even in .NET 7. I say ValidateOnStart, and it does nothing until I try to retrieve an actual instance of the settings class, just like before. Very frustrating.

Comment: @Mel It seems to depend on the kind of application. In a Worker Service, this code will throw as soon as `host.Run();` is called. However, in a Windows Forms application, where the entry point is something like `Application.Run(ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Form1>());` you won't see an error until an IOptions instance is retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a generic `ConfigureAndValidate` method to validate immediately and "fail fast".

To summarize the steps:

1. Call `serviceCollection.Configure` for your options
2. Do `serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope()`
3. Get the options instance with `scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<T>>` (remember to take the `.Value`)
4. Validate it using `Validator.TryValidateObject`

```
public static class ConfigExtensions
{
    public static void ConfigureAndValidate<T>(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, Action<T> configureOptions) where T : class, new()
    {
        // Inspired by https://blog.bredvid.no/validating-configuration-in-asp-net-core-e9825bd15f10
        serviceCollection.Configure(configureOptions);

        using (var scope = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope())
        {
            var options = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<T>>();
            var optionsValue = options.Value;
            var configErrors = ValidationErrors(optionsValue).ToArray();
            if (!configErrors.Any())
            {
                return;
            }

            var aggregatedErrors = string.Join(",", configErrors);
            var count = configErrors.Length;
            var configType = typeof(T).FullName;
            throw new ApplicationException($"{configType} configuration has {count} error(s): {aggregatedErrors}");
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> ValidationErrors(object obj)
    {
        var context = new ValidationContext(obj, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        Validator.TryValidateObject(obj, context, results, true);
        foreach (var validationResult in results)
        {
            yield return validationResult.ErrorMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Update .NET 8

### TLDR;

Using `[ValidateObjectMembers]` on the nested object in the options class also validates the data annotations in the nested object. Example:

```
public class XYOptions {
 [ValidateObjectMembers]
 public PasswordOptions Password { get; init; } = null!;

 public class UsernameOptions
 {
     [Range(0, int.MaxValue)]
     public int MinLength { get; init; } = 0;
     // other properties with (or without) data annotations
 }
}
```

This was introduced with .NET 8 in [this PR](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/90275)

### Explanation

As @L.Vallet has pointed out, the best strategy to validate options is by adding them with dependency injection and then call the method `.ValidateDataAnnotations()` like this:

```
builder.Services.AddOptions<XYOptions>()
    .BindConfiguration(XYOptions.Path) // Path in appsettings.json
    .ValidateDataAnnotations();
```

If you also want the data annotations to be checked on startup of the project, you can add `.ValidateOnStartup` like this:

```
builder.Services.AddOptions<XYOptions>()
    .BindConfiguration(XYOptions.Path) // Path in appsettings.json
    .ValidateDataAnnotations();
    .ValidateOnStart();
```

As some more complex options have neste objects in them, it was necessary to use a custom NUGET package in order for the neste annotations to work, this is no longer the case as of now. You can use the `[ValidateObjectMembers]` annotation like this:

```
public class XYOptions {
 [ValidateObjectMembers]
 public PasswordOptions Password { get; init; } = null!;

 public class UsernameOptions
 {
     [Range(0, int.MaxValue)]
     public int MinLength { get; init; } = 0;
     // other properties with (or without) data annotations
 }
}
```

This will work recursively and for all nested objects of the XYOptions class.