# Can ValidateDataAnnotations() throw exception already on startup?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, validation, data-annotations

For demonstration purposes I created a new web API project:

```
dotnet new webapp
```

I followed the documentations of the "Options Pattern" regarding data validation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0

So I added some (test) options class `PositionOptions.cs`:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class PositionOptions
{
    public const string Position = "Position";

    [Required]
    [MinLength(3)]
    public string Title { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    [Required]
    [MinLength(3)]
    public string Name { get; set; } = String.Empty;
}
```

And I added code to my `Program.cs` (Statup.cs seems to be no more) to add those options and add/trigger the validations for them:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddOptions<PositionOptions>()
    .Bind(builder.Configuration.GetSection(PositionOptions.Position))
    .ValidateDataAnnotations()
...
```

The appsettings.json looks like this:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "Position": {
    "Title": "",
    "Name": ""
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I expected the `OptionsValidationException` to be thrown inside Startup.cs when the app starts. But instead the data seems to get only validated when I make use of the options (`PositionOptions`) for example inside a controller. So the app crashes on usages of those options which I think is not ideal.

I would prefer it the app would throw the exception during startup. Is there a (nice) way this validation can be forced to occur during startup?

Comment: Could you pls try `ValidateOnStart` ([see here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/src/OptionsBuilderExtensions.cs))?

Comment: @mu88 how can I use this extension method, I cannot find it. Wenn I do "dotnet --version" I see that I have 6.0.101 installed, shouldn't it be included? App targets net core 3.1, language version 9.

Comment: According to the [PR](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/51171), it seems to be a .NET 6 feature. Upgrading your app should work, but you can also try to backport the code or try to update the NuGet package `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`

Comment: @mu88 - well I cannot use net6 at the moment, it needs to stay net core 3.1 - I was also unable to include the extension method with using the DI 6.0.0 package. I inspected it with dotPeek but I cannot find this extension method inside.

Comment: So than you can try to implement the extension method within your own codebase according to Microsoft's original one

Comment: @mu88 I've now implemented the extension method fromt his answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56710028/605578 and it suits my needs for the moment.